Restrict a specific group to access a directory and drive
I have created a group "restricted" and added a user "user1" to this group , how can I restrict this group to access some specified directory and drive.

What do you mean with "restrict"? Do you want only the members but not anyone else to have access? Or do you want everyone but the members of the group have access? Two very different scenarios.

You can change the owner group of the directory.
chgrp -R <group_name> <directory_name>
-R - for recursive.
Replace <group_name> and <directory_name> with your actual group and directory names, respectively.
See man chgrp for more details.

That's not a complete answer. Apart from the group ownership change you should also discuss chmod to adjust the permissions. Just changing the ownership won't do what the OP wants to do.

@MLu: Good luck with that :)
